# symfony2 assets in changed web folder

Tags: symfony, assets

I'm using Symfony2 in my project and I changed web root ditectory. I followed instructions on this page http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html. Now my project structure looks like this:

```
/frontend - the new web root dir
/myproject - the project dir
```

Then i'm installed and dumped assets

```
php app/console assets:dump
php app/console assetic:install ../frontend --symlink
```

Most things works fine. But the problem is that I can't acces to any asset in /bundles directory, Symfony returns error

```
No route found for "GET /bundles/..."
```

But I can see my assets in this directory in explorer (symlinks created correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Is your web server configured to follow symlinks? Without knowing which web server you are using, as an example in apache you need to set the `FollowSymLinks` option. Alternatively, remove the symlink option when doing `assets:install`.

Also, it's probably just a typo, but you've got the commands for installing assets and dumping assetic a bit muddled in your question - should be something like this:

```
php app/console assets:install --symlink ../frontend
php app/console assetic:dump -e dev
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answer. I'm using xampp, php 5.5, Windows 8.1. I've tried to install assets without symlink, that's not helped.

Comment: So in your frontend folder, you have a bundles folder, and the assets that you are getting 'No route found for' is installed in the expected path? In my experience, assets are usually found by the webserver before handing off to symfony app.php. How about permissions, does the web server have read access to the assets?